# Dynamic link doesn't function in thymeleaf

Tags: html, jsp, thymeleaf

I want to convert the following link in my jsp file to thymeleaf :

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <a href='<spring:url value="/users/${user.id}" />'>
                    ${user.name}
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

like this :

```
<tbody>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td th:text="${user.name}"><a href="/users" 
                th:href="@{/users(id=${user.id})}" >user name</a></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

but it doesn't function, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try like this please , th:href="@{/users/{id}(id=${user.id})}"

Comment: thanks Gurkan for the comment but it didn't work for me

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You might need to preprocess ${user.id}

Comment: yes  ${user.id} should be evaluated to an integer but I
think this is done by th:each="user : ${users}" 
each User object has an id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem referring to [usingthymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)
it might be useful for someone else, this code
generates what I was looking for: /users/3
where 3 is the {id}

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <td ><a th:text="${user.name}" 
    href="/users" th:href="@{'/users/' + ${user.id}}" >user name</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Ah yes, correct, should have the quotes in there if that's what you're seeking.